# What is best practice for web input control to gather multiple strings?

Tags: html, asp.net, user-interface, web

I am looking to add to a web form the ability for users to enter mutiple strings. It should work like the tags input to new questions on stackoverflow.

Is there a smaple on teh web of such a UI control for asp.net?

Or is there another solution for accepting multiple tags (of text/ strings) in a nice neet ui control?

(I didnt find anything usefull in the HTML5 set of controls.)

NOTE: for use with a asp.net web form (post backs) application

Answer (score 1):

I think [TextExt](http://textextjs.com/) plugin is best for you. very handly and useful.

### TextExt Plugin for jQuery

> TextExt is a plugin for jQuery which is designed to provide
>   functionality such as tag input and autocomplete.
>
> The core design principle behind TextExt is modularity and
>   extensibility. Each piece of functionality is separated from the main
>   core and can act individually or together with other plugins.

### Features:

- Tags
- Autocomplete
- AJAX loading
- Placeholder text
- Arrow
- … and much more!

### How To Use:

The steps to using TextExt are as follows:

- Specify which plugins you need via the plugins option
- Configure each plugin individually if necessary
- Enjoy!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#textarea').textext({
        plugins : 'tags prompt focus autocomplete ajax arrow',
        tagsItems : [ 'Basic', 'JavaScript', 'PHP', 'Scala' ],
        prompt : 'Add one...',
        ajax : {
            url : '/manual/examples/data.json',
            dataType : 'json',
            cacheResults : true
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: this will be used in a asp.net web form (post back) application, so i will need access to the values on the server side somehow with the rest of the form inputs.

Comment: @kacalapy there is no problem in using with any server language. and it works with postbacks too. the selected tags are sent with a hidden field in page. I use this plugin in asp.net and php.